# Performing selector on superView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, selector

I have an `UICollectionView` which uses `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`to determine when the user has scrolled to the bottom.

The owner of my `UICollectionView` has a method which sends a command to a server and asks for more data.

What I want to do is to perform a selector on the owner (my viewcontroller) from my `UICollectionView`, and specifically from within `scrollViewDidScroll`.

I try to do it using the following code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    if (offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        [[self superView] performSelector:@selector(onScrolledToBottom) withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

**Note**: the selector `onScrolledToBottom` is a `SEL` property of my `UICollectionView`.

**The error I am getting** says:

```
-[UIView onScrolledToBottom]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc641e76e00
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView onScrolledToBottom]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc641e76e00'
```

---

**EDIT**

I've stripped my code down to fit this question.

I have the followin in my `ViewController.m`

```
....

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self initCollectionView];
}
....

- (void) getMoreInfo{
    NSLog(@"Getting more info");
}

- (void) initCollectionView{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50.0, 60.0);
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 20, 0);
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320.f, 30.f);

    myCollectionView *mVC = [myCollectionView alloc] init: self.view: flowLayout: @selector(getMoreInfo)];
}
```

And for my `myCollectionView` the `.h`and `.m`files look as following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myCollectionView : UICollectionView<UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>{
    UIView *parentView;
    SEL onScrolledToBottom;
}

@property UIView *parentView;
@property SEL onScrolledToBottom;

- (id)init: (UIView*) parent: (UICollectionViewLayout *)layout: (SEL)onScrolledToBottomSEL;
@end
```

and

```
#import "myCollectionView.h"

@implementation myCollectionView

@synthesize parentView = parentView;
@synthesize onScrolledToBottom = onScrollToBotton;

- (id)init: (UIView*) parent: (UICollectionViewLayout *)layout: (SEL)onScrolledToBottomSEL{
    self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, parent.frame.size.width, parent.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout: layout];
    if (self) {
        parentView = parent;
        self.delegate = self;
        self.dataSource = self;
        onScrolledToBottom = onScrolledToBottomSEL;
    }

    return self;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    if (offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        [parentView performSelector:@selector(onScrolledToBottom) withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `onScrolledToBottom`  method

Comment: @saif I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean if I've put it in the `.h` of my ViewController?

Comment: yes, put the header file.

Comment: onScrolledToBottom should be a method,not just a property

Comment: @saif I edited my question and included my code.

Comment: Your error is saying that `[self superView]` is returning a plain `UIView` rather than a `myCollectionView`.

Comment: You're getting the superview instead of the parent controller, that's one. Secondly, you shouldn't try to do it this way. Instead use a protocol and pass your controller as a delegate to your custom collectionview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the superview instead of the parent controller, that's one. Secondly, you shouldn't try to do it this way. Instead use a protocol and pass your controller as a delegate to your custom collectionview.

```
@protocol MyCollectionViewScrollProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)scrolledToBottom;

@end
```

Then in your ViewController implement this protocol and in your CollectionView

create a weak property delegate like this:

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) id<MyCollectionViewScrollProtocol> delegate;
```

Then you'll be able to call it

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    if (offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        [self.delegate  scrolledToBottom];
    }
}
```

and don't forget to set the delegate property from the controller.

---

**Edit by OP:**

The controller should contain the following code in the `.h`file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ViewControllerProtocol <NSObject>
    - (void) Pong;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ViewControllerProtocol>

@end
```

and the following code somewhere in the `.m` file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import UIKit;
#import "myUnit.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myUnit mU = [[myUnit alloc] init];
    mU.linkToController = self;
    [mU Ping];
}

......

- (void) Pong{
    NSLog(@"Pong");
}

......
```

**The unit that wants to access the controller** needs to have the following code in the `.h`file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface myUnit : NSObject {
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ViewControllerProtocol> linkToController;

- (void)Ping;

@end
```

And the unit that wants to access the controller needs to have the following code in the `.m`file:

```
#import "myUnit.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation myUnit

- (void) Ping {
    NSLog(@"Ping");
    [self.linkToController Pong];
}


@end
```

Comment: Dod not seen this answer when I was typing my :) But this is the right way to do this :)

Comment: I found an answer thanks to the inspiration from your answer. I wrote an answer.

Comment: @StanislavAgeev it seems as if the delegate property can be named something else, in my case I named it to `@property(weak, nonatomic) id<MyCollectionViewScrollProtocol> linkToController;`. Is this an acceptable way of doing it? If Yes, then your answer is correct, and I have successfully managed to solve my problem, and I'd like to edit your answer and add my full sample code .

Comment: Sure, you can use any property name.

Answer (score 1):

The `collectionView.parentView` will be `ViewController.view`, which is totally a `UIView`, doesn't have a method called `onScrolledToBottom`.

Here is a approach if I right about what you want, but **IT'S REALLY REALLY A BAD WAY** to do this.

in `ViewController.m`

```
....    

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self initCollectionView];
}
....    

- (void) getMoreInfo{
    NSLog(@"Getting more info");
}    

- (void) initCollectionView{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50.0, 60.0);
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 20, 0);
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320.f, 30.f);    

    myCollectionView *mVC = [myCollectionView alloc] initWithParentViewController:self layout:flowLayout selector:@selector(getMoreInfo)];
}
```

in `myCollectionView.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    

@interface myCollectionView : UICollectionView<UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>{
    UIViewController *_parentViewController;
    SEL _onScrolledToBottom;
}    

@property(weak) UIViewController *parentViewController;
@property SEL onScrolledToBottom;    

- (id)initWithParentViewController:(UIView *)parentViewController layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout selector:(SEL)onScrolledToBottomSEL;
@end
```

in `myCollectionView.m`

```
#import "myCollectionView.h"    

@implementation myCollectionView    

@synthesize parentViewController = _parentViewController;
@synthesize onScrolledToBottom = _onScrollToBotton;    

- (id)initWithParentViewController:(UIView *)parentViewController layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout selector:(SEL)onScrolledToBottomSEL{
    self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, parent.frame.size.width, parent.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout: layout];
    if (self) {
        _parentViewController = parentViewController;
        self.delegate = self;
        self.dataSource = self;
        _onScrolledToBottom = onScrolledToBottomSEL;
    }    
    return self;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    if (offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        [_parentViewController performSelector:@selector(onScrolledToBottom) withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

**WARNING:**

- In `MVC` there should be a `Controller` to implement 
  the protocol, not a view.
- Class name's first character must be capitalized, you should use `MyCollectionView` instead of `myCollectionView` as a class name.
- When use property, the LLVM compiler will automatically generate a member variable, no need to declare it again.
- In this case use `protocol-delegate` is the best way.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out on my own too haha but can I ask why this approach is bad?

Answer (score 1):

Your "myCollectionView" should have a delegate (you will have to create a protocol for that) with some method along the line:

```
- (void)myCollectionViewDidScrollToBottom:(myCollectionView *)collectionView
```

By convention view will pass itself to this method (just like any tableView delegate methods). Then in the `initCollectionView` after `myCollectionView *mVC = [myCollectionView alloc] init...` you will have to set this delegate to the current view controller and implement that method.

```
mVC.delegate = self;

... 
some other place in code
...

- (void)myCollectionViewDidScrollToBottom:(myCollectionView *)collectionView {
    //do what's need to be done ;)
}
```

Now your "myCollectionView" does not care where it's just and by "who". Anyone who would like to use it can implement this method and be a delegate for that view with any custom logic. That is in this method you would call any required methods and any other things.

**How this works:**

1. View when scrolls down notifies it's delegate about this event
2. Delegate handles all the logic what's need to be done

:)

Answer (score 0):

First I want to say thank you to all of you.

I read through everything you guys wrote and I was inspired.

Especially Stanislav Ageev's answer where he said

> You're getting the superview instead of the parent controller...

.

I tried to pass the controller itself as a `UIViewController` instead of view of the controller.

And I also removed the `@selector()` from within the `scrollViewDidScroll` and passed the selector directly.

**EDIT** I missed zy.lius answer. Credit goes to him/her for posting an answer which basically explains what I've done here even though I figured this out on my own. Sorry.

My code now looks like this (.h/.m):

Controller

```
....

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self initCollectionView];
}
....

- (void) getMoreInfo{
    NSLog(@"Getting more info");
}

- (void) initCollectionView{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50.0, 60.0);
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 20, 0);
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320.f, 30.f);

    myCollectionView *mVC = [myCollectionView alloc] init: self: flowLayout: @selector(getMoreInfo)];
}
```

myCollectionView.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myCollectionView : UICollectionView<UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>{
    UICollectionView *parentController;
    SEL onScrolledToBottom;
}

@property UICollectionView *parentController;
@property SEL onScrolledToBottom;

- (id)init: (UICollectionView*) parent: (UICollectionViewLayout *)layout: (SEL)onScrolledToBottomSEL;
@end
```

and the .m file:

```
#import "myCollectionView.h"

@implementation myCollectionView

@synthesize parentController = parentController;
@synthesize onScrolledToBottom = onScrollToBotton;

- (id)init: (UIView*) parent: (UICollectionViewLayout *)layout: (SEL)onScrolledToBottomSEL{
    self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, parent.view.frame.size.width, parent.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout: layout];
    if (self) {
        parentController = parent;
        self.delegate = self;
        self.dataSource = self;
        onScrolledToBottom = onScrolledToBottomSEL;
    }

    return self;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    if (offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        [parentController performSelector:@onScrolledToBottom withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine and this could be used to communicate with the main controller in various ways.

And it is very simple.

Thanks again for inspiring me to find the most efficient solution.

Comment: Well, this answer is incorrect in a few ways. First of all you have a memory leak since after introduction of ARC implicit property attribute is strong, so you're basically creating a retain loop between the view and the controller. Secondly, the answer has loads of typos which make it incorrect. And third, you should consider using a protocol since it will reduce errors and abstract the controller out as it supposed to be (Children are not supposed to have explicit knowledge about their parents).

Comment: @StanislavAgeev could you link the document regarding protocol? I might need to educate myself about it so I can implement it properly

Comment: check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html and look at my answer. This will solve both the memory leak and the missing abstraction layer.